# Not able to get output with Pythons multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.4

so I am trying to delve into multiprocessing with python. I went to the python 3 website, to see some example code, and they have this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I put it in my IDE and ran it, but nothing happens. If I run the debugger, it takes me to the process, and I see that everything happens, but just running it does nothing. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code is working here :`http://ideone.com/9kcQru`

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

## output : hello bob

There is something wrong with your environment

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it didn't work. Also isn't p.join() important to have at the end?